# How can I fix unnecessary print statements from being printed while i run this function containing two while loops?

Tags: python, printing, while-loop

As you can see I'm pretty new and I even had trouble phrasing my problem, but my issue is say type is "A" when you quit the loop it prints out items and total twice when I only need items and total. Secondly when type is "T" I only want the total to print when I quit the loop but it prints out the above statements that I need for my first loop.

```
def ar(type):
    total = 0
    items = ""
    print("Input an integer to add to the total or \"Q\" to quit")
    while type == "A":
        user_input = input("Enter an integer or \"Q\": ")
        if user_input.isdigit():
            items += user_input + "\n"
            total += int(user_input)
        elif user_input == "q":
            break
        elif user_input == "Q":
            break
        else:
            print(user_input, " is not an invalid input")
    print("Items \n" + items) 
    print("\nTotal \n" + str(total))          
    while type == "T":
        user_input = input("Enter an integer or \"Q\": ")
        if user_input.isdigit():
            total += int(user_input)
        elif user_input == "q":
            break
        elif user_input == "Q":
            break
        else:
            print(user_input, " is not an invalid input")
    print("\nTotal \n" + str(total))
```

This is what the output should look like:

Input an integer to add to the total or "Q" to quit

Enter an integer or "Q": 3

Enter an integer or "Q": 6

Enter an integer or "Q": 24

Enter an integer or "Q": 17

Enter an integer or "Q": 61

Enter an integer or "Q": nine

nine is invalid input

Enter an integer or "Q": q

Items

3

6

24

17

61

Total

111

call with "T"(print only the total)

Input an integer to add to the total or "Q" to quit

Enter an integer or "Q": 5

Enter an integer or "Q": 7

Enter an integer or "Q": Quit

Total

12

**This is what my output looks like:**

If i call ar("A")

Input an integer to add to the total or "Q" to quit

Enter an integer or "Q": 3

Enter an integer or "Q": 6

Enter an integer or "Q": 24

Enter an integer or "Q": 17

Enter an integer or "Q": 61

Enter an integer or "Q": nine

nine is invalid input

Enter an integer or "Q": q

Items

3

6

24

17

61

Total

111

Total

111

if i call with ar("T")

Input an integer to add to the total or "Q" to quit

Items

Total

0

Enter an integer or "Q": 5

Enter an integer or "Q": 7

Enter an integer or "Q": Quit

Total

12

p.s. this is not HW I'm taking a free course on edx and this is just practice.

Comment: You may want to try this method : https://rubberduckdebugging.com/ - it looks like a joke but you'd be surprised how effective it is when strictly applied. I personally use a plush penguin instead but it works just as well.

Answer (score 0):

Few things:

```
print("\nTotal \n" + str(total))
```

appears twice in your code - once after each `while`. If you need to print the total in both cases, remove the one after the first `while` and leave only the one in the end of file.

You can change

`elif user_input == "q":
            break
        elif user_input == "Q":
            break`

to

```
elif user_input == "q" or user_input == "Q":
    break
```

`type` is a variable that your function receives, and it doesn't change in the function. There is no reason to use `while`, you can use `if type == 'A': ... elif type == 'T': ...` command

Comment: `elif user_input.lower() == "q"`

Comment: `elif user_input in ("q","Q")`

Comment: The requirements want me to include a while loop in the code. I was thinking of changing it to while True: and putting all my code inside.